# How long before idle Lambda function transitions to Inactive state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch-events

Following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/tracking-the-state-of-lambda-functions/) AWS blog, I can see that

> A function transitions to the *Inactive* state when it has been idle **long enough** for the Lambda service to reclaim the external resources that were configured for it.

So what is **long enough**? I have Lambda functions deployed in a VPC that may be idle for weeks or months, and I'd like to avoid the `Lambda.ResourceNotReadyException` and subsequent `502` status codes my client receives because the function is *Inactive* and a new network interface needs to be configured.

I just need the Lambdas to remain in *Active* state; don't need warm starts so not wanting to pay for Lambda's Provisioned Concurrency. I'm thinking to just trigger each Lambda in the VPC with a CloudWatch Event on some regular interval. I assume I could trigger once per day but really curious if I can find a more optimal solution here.

Comment: I don't think you'll find a definitive answer... It's like asking how long a value will stay in a cache -- it depends on how 'busy' the system is and what other functions are being invoked. You might also enjoy reading this series of articles: [Operating Lambda: Performance optimization – Part 1 | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/)

Comment: I would setup an eventbridge rule that gets triggered if the Lambda function state changes, so that you can then invoke it. I can't seem to find, however, any information on whether this event is actually available

Comment: @MarkB as far as I can tell it's a state specific to the lambda function itself. The documentation in fact talks about *a* function and not *all* functions

Comment: I've never actually seen a VPC Lambda function go into an "inactive" state in practice. I had to dig into the documentation to make sure this is still even a thing. There is a mention of it in the latest documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/foundation-networking.html and it says it happens after the Lambda function "remains idle for consecutive weeks". So I guess you may run into this issue after 2 weeks of idle time.

Comment: @Paolo thanks for the clarification, I was confused about the subject being discussed.

Comment: Like Mark, I've also never seen this state. I actually have some lambda functions in my account which haven't been run in years and they actually still result as `Active`. So if setting up an Eventbridge rule is not an option (and I think it isn't, because I couldn't find any AWS lambda event for this) then you could simply run another lambda function every week to keep the main one `Active`.

Comment: @MarkB no worries!

Comment: @MarkB So I actually did experience this in one of my accounts. Only have a couple microservices in the account right now, and I confirmed that all the account's Lambda functions were idle for 2 weeks + 8 hrs. Appreciate you digging up the docs - I think the section here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/foundation-networking.html#foundation-nw-eni-create mentioning "idle for consecutive weeks" is probably as close as we'll come to a documented answer from AWS. Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*long enough* is ~14 days.

I've gone through every mention of inactive & idle in the AWS Lambda docs.

The blog post you have linked mentions ['long enough'](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/tracking-the-state-of-lambda-functions/#:%7E:text=A%20function%20transitions%20to%20the%20Inactive%20state%20when%20it%20has%20been%20idle%20long%20enough%20for%20the%20Lambda%20service%20to%20reclaim%20the%20external%20resources%20that%20were%20configured%20for%20it.):

> A function transitions to the Inactive state when it has been idle **long enough** for the Lambda service to reclaim the external resources that were configured for it.

The *Lambda function states* section of the docs also mentions ['long enough'](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/functions-states.html#:%7E:text=Inactive%20%E2%80%93%20A%20function%20becomes%20inactive%20when%20it%20has%20been%20idle%20long%20enough%20for%20Lambda%20to%20reclaim%20the%20external%20resources%20that%20were%20configured%20for%20it.):

> `Inactive` – A function becomes inactive when it has been idle **long enough** for Lambda to reclaim the external resources that were configured for it.

The *Private Networking* section of the docs mentions ['consecutive weeks'](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/foundation-networking.html#foundation-nw-eni-create:%7E:text=If%20a%20Lambda%20function%20remains%20idle%20for%20consecutive%20weeks%2C%20Lambda%20reclaims%20the%20unused%20Hyperplane%20ENIs%20and%20sets%20the%20function%20state%20to%20idle.):

> If a Lambda function remains idle for **consecutive weeks**, Lambda reclaims the unused Hyperplane ENIs and sets the function state to idle.

However, the *Lambda SnapStart and function states* section of the docs is as closest as we get to a real answer: ['14 days'](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/snapstart-activate.html#snapstart-function-states:%7E:text=Inactive%20%E2%80%93%20The%20function%20version%20hasn%27t%20been%20invoked%20for%2014%20days.).

> `Inactive` – The function version hasn't been invoked for **14 days**. When the function version becomes Inactive, Lambda deletes the snapshot.

My own testing also validates it to be approximately ~14 days.

---

I've submitted feedback to the AWS Lambda team to update the documentation to be more clear, or provide reasoning as to the lack of clarity on duration. It's unfortunate that it's not consistent.

I'll update my answer if/when I hear back.